# if ($("#" id " img").is(":hidden"))

Tags: jquery

JavaScript Newbie. I have learnt basics only. I am creating a game in JavaScript . But I don't know what this " img" means. It is used many times in the code. And this is confusing me. Please help me out.

```
$("#card div").click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($("#"+id+" img").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#"+id+" img").fadeIn('slow');
        if (imageopen == "") {
            showimg = id;
            imageopen = $("#"+id+" img").attr("src");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `img` is an image tag, it's looking for the `img` descendants of the element you clicked. Although `$(this).find('img').is(':hidden')` would have the same results

Comment: Not necessarily, `find('img')` would be equivalent, `children()` is limited to only searching the immediate children of an  element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad code.

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
if ($("#"+id+" img").is(":hidden"))
```

This means get the `id` of the element that was clicked. Let's imagine this `id` was the string `foobar`. Then we build a string that ends up looking like `#foobar img`. That is to say, the strings are put together (it's called concatenation). They are used to make a jQuery selector, which finds `img` elements within `#foobar`.

This is a bad way to do this. The simple way is to use jQuery's `find` method:

```
var img = $(this).find('img');
if (img.is(':hidden')) {
    img.fadeIn('slow');

    // etc
}
```

---

It's also worth pointing out that `$(this).attr('id')` is *always* a bad idea. You don't actually need the `id` value to do what you are doing, of course, but this is useful for future reference. `this` is a reference to the element that was clicked. You can access the `id` property of an element by doing `this.id`. It will return exactly the same as `$(this).attr('id')`, but more efficiently.

Comment: Also `this.id` (I know *you* know, the OP, I imagine, doesn't). @rain: internally jQuery  implements `find()`, there's no saving to be made using context.

Comment: @raina77ow Well, that does work, but to my mind it's less intuitive and explicit. Moreover, it's exactly the same behind the scenes.

Comment: Worth noting that the reason this is more efficent (storing the DOM element in a variable) is because without it JavaScript has to search the dom tree each time.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, I've added that. I didn't initially because it's not actually needed in this operation.

Comment: @raina77ow Behind the scenes, `$('img', this)` is converted to `$(this).find('img')`. [See the source code.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/679536ee4b7a92ae64a5f58d90e9cc38c001e807/src/core/init.js#L86)

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, my mistake; checked only `find` method. Now I wonder why one particular library I work with is literally littered with `$(foo, bar)` - I've been told it's because of (better) speed, but never checked that out. )

Answer (score 0):

`img` is the HTML tag `<img src="" alt=""/>` contained in the DOM element `#id`

Answer (score 0):

`$("#"+id+" img")` mean you are searching tag `<img>` inside the container tag with the id `#id`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#"+id+" img")
```

is:

```
$("#56 img")
```

where 56 would be the `id attr` of any tag, children of `id=card` tag.

And this references:

```
<anytag id=56><img ...>
```

Actually, references the `img` tag above.

Of course, `.is(":hidden")` returns true if the referenced tag is hidden (`display: hidden;`).